# How to import 3 tables dump into database using script?

Tags: module, database, import, sql

I want to include 3 tables SQL dump into that database, how to add it by using a custom module or script or any best practice.

Comment: Export table sql and login mysql and run mysql command?

Comment: I can't access my mysql directly, is there any way to import my tables? any php script?

Comment: check this link https://phppot.com/php/import-csv-file-into-mysql-using-php/#:~:text=php%20use%20Phppot%5CDataSource%3B%20require_once,10000%2C%20%22%2C%22))%20!%3D%3D

Comment: I need to import tables dump

Comment: @zus let me know if given solution works for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put your mysql dump file `xyz.sql` in **pub** folder and create a file with below code to import in pub folder

`pub\custom_import.php`

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "root";
$db_name = "m242ee";

$sql = file_get_contents('ktpl_bannerslider_banner_slider.sql');

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

/* execute multi query */
$result = $mysqli->multi_query($sql);

if($result){
    echo 'Sql imported successfully.';
}
```

In order to import multiple dump files you can modify above script as per your requirements.

Now execute this file from browser for ex. http://example.com/custom_import.php

If your magento setup is not pointing to pub then do this same process on magento root.